# dropdown is hiding behind parent element

Tags: css, overflow, dropdown

```css
#container {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 85px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 0 33.39%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>title</div>
    <component></component>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>title</div>
    <component></component>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>title</div>
    <component></component>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>title</div>
    <component></component>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>title</div>
    <component></component>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have container in which i show three elements a time and hide others using overflow-x:scroll so i can scroll the elements . on clicking component a dropdown is shown but the dropdown gets hidden and not displayed. on using overflow-y:visible for container sets overflow-y to auto .Is there a way to show dropdown on using overflow-y:visible.

inside component

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="position:relative;display:flex">
      <button>show</button> 
     <dropdown-list><dropdown-list>           
  </div>
</div>
```

on clicking the button and using variables dropdown-list is either shown or hidden

inside dropdown-list

```html
<div id="container" style="display:flex;position:absolute;flex-direction:column">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your dropdown , please post more detailed code and tell us what result you are going to achieve

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/